# how to find and replace in unix

Tags: regex, linux, unix

I have an XML file having tags `<![CDATA[]]>` & I need to replace this tag with

```
 <![CDATA[XXX]]>
```

when am trying to replace using 
sed command :`sed 's/<![CDATA[]]>/<![CDATA[XXX]]>/g' stores.xml`

i can't see any changes on my file.

Please help me in finding the solution.

Comment: `[` and `]` are reserved characters in regex. Escape them as `\[` and `\]`.

Comment: You are seeing the replacement outputed in your screen. If you want the file to be updated, add `-i` to your command: `sed -i 's/...'` or redirect the current command to a file `sed 's/...' file > new_file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -i 's/<!\[CDATA\[\]\]>/<!\[CDATA\[XXX\]\]>/g' stores.xml
```

You need to escape the brackets, otherwise they mean in regexp syntax "any of the enclosed characters".

To see the changes applied to an existing file, use the option `-i`.  Alternatively you can use

```
sed ... < stores.xml > new_stores.xml
```

Which, for testing at least, might be more of your taste because it creates a new file with the result and leaves the original untouched.  (Use `mv new_stores.xml stores.xml` afterwards in case the result looks fine.)